# jHipster UML, Invalid Type Exception with Modelio

Tags: uml, jhipster, modelio

I'm trying to generate the entities on jHipster, from the .xmi Modelio UML file, this error came up:

> An error has occurred:
>       WrongTypeException Error message:
>       The type 'ELong' isn't supported by JHipster.

Comment: In fact, Long is not an UML predefined type but it is a Ecore Type.
So if you need an ecore xmi model you can stick to Long i.e. ELong or if you need a OMG xmi dfile you can change your long to float for example.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was after exporting the .xmi file, some of the entities attributes where exported in an unsupported jHipster type. 
The solution can be: open the .xmi file, find the invalid `ELong` type and replace it for a valid `Long` type, also make sure that 
`href = pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml`